# How to make a query in codeigniter4?

Tags: php, vue.js, codeigniter-4

I am trying to make a query using ci4. But I keep getting the same error. I don't know where the cause is. Can anyone help me.

This is my controller

```php
    public function search(){

            
        $this->db = \Config\Database::connect();
        $user_id= $this->request->getPOST('search'); 

        $sql = "SELECT pay_daftarid.di_id, pay_daftarid.di_nama, pay_daftarid.di_nokp, pay_daftarid.di_telefon, pay_daftarid.di_emel,
                pay_daftarid.di_alamat1, pay_daftarid.di_poskod,pay_daftarid.di_kod_bandar, pay_daftarid.di_kod_negeri,
                pay_daftarid.di_kod_negara,
                hrp_ruj_negara.keterangan as negara,
                hrp_ruj_negeri.keterangan as negeri,
                hrp_ruj_bandar.nama_bandar
                FROM pay_daftarid
                JOIN hrp_ruj_negara ON hrp_ruj_negara.kod = di_kod_negara,
                JOIN hrp_ruj_negeri ON hrp_ruj_negeri.kod = di_kod_negeri,
                JOIN hrp_ruj_bandar ON kod_bandar = di_kod_bandar
                WHERE di_nokp = '$user_id'";
            
        $result = $this->db->query($sql);
        $data = $result->getRow();
        return $this->respond($data);       
  

    }
```

The result should return a one record based on the searched id ($user_id)

And this is my vue.js

```js
get_id(){
            var self = this;

            $.post(base_url + '/api/seminar/search', {
                search: self.search, //self.search   
            }, function(res){ //res adalah daripada API
                self.selected = res.data[0]; 
                console.log(self.contents[0].di_nama);
            });
            
        },
```

And this is my error

```
> <br />
<b>Fatal error</b>:  Uncaught CodeIgniter\Format\Exceptions\FormatException: Failed to parse json string, error: &quot;Type is not supported&quot;. in C:\ci4_project\paygate\vendor\codeigniter4\framework\system\Format\JSONFormatter.php:41
Stack trace:
#0 C:\ci4_project\paygate\vendor\codeigniter4\framework\system\Format\JSONFormatter.php(41): CodeIgniter\Format\Exceptions\FormatException::forInvalidJSON('Type is not sup...')
#1 C:\ci4_project\paygate\vendor\codeigniter4\framework\system\API\ResponseTrait.php(348): CodeIgniter\Format\JSONFormatter-&gt;format(Array)
#2 C:\ci4_project\paygate\vendor\codeigniter4\framework\system\API\ResponseTrait.php(99): CodeIgniter\Debug\Exceptions-&gt;format(Array)
#3 C:\ci4_project\paygate\vendor\codeigniter4\framework\system\Debug\Exceptions.php(132): CodeIgniter\Debug\Exceptions-&gt;respond(Array, 500)
#4 [internal function]: CodeIgniter\Debug\Exceptions-&gt;exceptionHandler(Object(ErrorException))
#5 {main}
  thrown in <b>C:\ci4_project\paygate\vendor\codeigniter4\framework\system\Format\JSONFormatter.php</b> on line <b>41</b><br />
{
    "title": "ErrorException",
    "type": "ErrorException",
    "code": 500,
    "message": "Uncaught CodeIgniter\\Format\\Exceptions\\FormatException: Failed to parse json string, error: \"Type is not supported\". in C:\\ci4_project\\paygate\\vendor\\codeigniter4\\framework\\system\\Format\\JSONFormatter.php:41\nStack trace:\n#0 C:\\ci4_project\\paygate\\vendor\\codeigniter4\\framework\\system\\Format\\JSONFormatter.php(41): CodeIgniter\\Format\\Exceptions\\FormatException::forInvalidJSON('Type is not sup...')\n#1 C:\\ci4_project\\paygate\\vendor\\codeigniter4\\framework\\system\\API\\ResponseTrait.php(348): CodeIgniter\\Format\\JSONFormatter->format(Array)\n#2 C:\\ci4_project\\paygate\\vendor\\codeigniter4\\framework\\system\\API\\ResponseTrait.php(99): CodeIgniter\\Debug\\Exceptions->format(Array)\n#3 C:\\ci4_project\\paygate\\vendor\\codeigniter4\\framework\\system\\Debug\\Exceptions.php(132): CodeIgniter\\Debug\\Exceptions->respond(Array, 500)\n#4 [internal function]: CodeIgniter\\Debug\\Exceptions->exceptionHandler(Object(ErrorException))\n#5 {main}\n  thrown",
    "file": "C:\\ci4_project\\paygate\\vendor\\codeigniter4\\framework\\system\\Format\\JSONFormatter.php",
    "line": 41,
    "trace": [
        {
            "function": "shutdownHandler",
            "class": "CodeIgniter\\Debug\\Exceptions",
            "type": "->",
            "args": []
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: can you try `var_dump($user_id)` to see what value it is receiving?

Comment: You don't bother to check that $db is connected before using it. You don't bother to check if $user_id contains anything before stuffing it into the SQL (thus introducing an SQL query injection vulnerability). You don't bother to see if the query returns a valid result before attempting to fetch data from it, and then you pass whatever that data is off to another function, respond, which appears to be complaining about it. Try checking these things before passing them on to the next line of code.